# Recommendation for Xamarin Android Service

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mobile-application

I am quite new to Android development and have been struggling with this for a long time.

Here's my scenario:
I have a cross-platform application and it needs to use the internet connection at some points (not all). In my application have a form at the end and it needs to be submitted to the database server by using a web service. It's all coded and working when the user has an internet connection. But I need to handle this without an internet connection.

What I'm planning is to create a file that contains all the information in the form and save it in local storage when there is no connection. And in the end my app will call to android service to start (User can either close or keep the main application). My service will run in the background and it'll check connection periodically(let's say after 10 minutes). When there is a connection, it'll submit the form and destroy itself.

This was my idea and I need to know, is this possible or not? If it's possible, what are the steps should I follow? Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Please share if you have any easy tips to handle this instead of using a service.

Comment: I would look at Android's WorkManager as you can apply `Constraints` on when to start a task (i.e. `NetworkType.CONNECTED`): Googles doc: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/ Xamarin blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-workmanager/

Comment: I tried to create a new android service application which uses WorkManager and I had this problem. I cant access my main application files from my new service. Do you have any thoughts about this or can I use WorkManager in my main application?

Comment: Maybe you could create a [Foreground Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services),check connection periodically in the service.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thanks mate. I also think to use a foreground service for this. Cause  I found that background services were limited after Oreo. So foreground service will be flexible in both older and latest android devices.